# How to show partial data from mysql database using express.js (in json)

Tags: express

I have a table named "store" in mysql database. I am using node and express.js to retrieve data from mysql database(in json form) but I am asked to make some changes in showing json data (but in database it will remain the same). I have 
12 columns of weekly opening and closing timings. But I want to show them in an array (in json), how can I do that?

I am getting all the data by running query "SELECT * FROM store". And showing all the data in json from, exactly as it is.

var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');

````
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "hennastore"
});

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
})

app.get('/hennaread', function (request, response) {
    con.query('select * from store', function (error, results) {
        if (error) {
            response.status(400).send('Error in database operation');
        } else {



            response.send(results);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Express server is listening on port 3000');
});```
````

Comment: Hi anss, your problem seems not related to mysql or express, but you face trouble transforming data from an input (mysql query result) into another form. If that's true, can you please just provide the data before and after the transformation, like so we can help you writing the transformation.

Comment: @Slim Thanks, the problem has solved. can you please tell me how to run sql query in javascript function.  (I am using express js and node js)

Comment: You are welcome. Consider validate the answer and/or giving point on response that helped you.

Comment: Please ask a new question for your new need, since q/a are referenced and the target is to provide searchable q/a database. (Can't you find help in the readme of the sql driver lib you use?)